# Use ecommerce.items fields with Ecommerce Custom Event

Tags: google-bigquery, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I would like to know if the ecommerce columns can be use with custom Tag Manager Event related to ecommerce.

I have set up a BigQuery Link on GA4 view and I received data. I see the "items" columns in the table schema.
[image]
If I create a custom event like below, using the same parameter syntax as a recommended event, will the "items" column be filled automatically?
[image]

Using the DebugView, with a a recommended and custom event, the display is different.
On the recommended event, i can see a "items" tab. Does that mean my custom event will not record my items?
[image]

If no, how can I pass large value onto the table with a custom event? for example a list of products. Using a normal parameter is cropping the value up to 20 characters unfortunately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to use an appropriate EEC event to send EEC values.

If you need to send a complex data srtucture with a regular event, then you're limited to using event properties and are a subject to its limitations.

You could create and modify GA4 events based on other events but [this option](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) is really simplistic and limited.

Unfortunately, GA4 is not really an enterprise analytics solution (like Adobe Analytics) hence it's quite limited in terms of the number and the size of the dimensions, as well as the complexity of post-processing and parsing of dimension values into subdimensions. They have to keep it cheap to maintain in order to make it a free-for-all product

You could, of course, split your dimensions into subdimensions with ETL, but that would imply having to process data after it's exported to BQ.

Comment: "You could, of course, split your dimensions into subdimensions with ETL, but that would imply having to process data after it's exported to BQ." My process will include this kind of thing. Could you clarify "split your dimensions into subdimensions" ?

Comment: So when you need to track a complex object, you can stringify the object, put it into a dimension, then during ETL you would parse the object out, split it into multiple columns/fields/dimensions in the new table and there you go. You just have to be careful about the length of the original dimension. I would suggest considering a bitmap or a similar design.

Comment: I did tried this solution in a event parameter, unfortunately the string is cut out after 100 characters. On BQ I can see 'event_dimensions' col with only 'hostname' in it. Is this what you are refering too?

Comment: What about creating a event based on 'view_item_list'? Will I be able to use 'items'? Can I copy the parameters and change the names of unused item properties? 
"You can't create and modify custom events based on parameters from the items array (e.g., item_brand, item_name, item_id) when you use gtag.js." [Link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10085872?hl=en#examples&zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cmodify-parameters%2Crename-an-existing-event%2Ccreate-an-event-from-an-existing-event%2Ctrigger-an-event-based-on-a-value). I am using GTM
Doing so is not display items in Debug view.

Comment: If you enable EEC for the tag, then sure, you should be able to set EEC fields in it. For the complex data structure like items, you would want to return an array of objects with a CJS. Just make sure the event name is one of the registered EEC events. Google won't let you use EEC for the events it doesn't expect it for. Since it wouldn't know how that EEC is to be reported on. And yeah, you will wreck native reporting doing so, but then who needs it if you have sql.

Comment: I mentionned using GA4 therefore , all ecommerce event are EEC if you want. I guess I had my solution I cannot use custom events for ecommerce but I can use recommended events with custom data such as custom parameters